# Chaining events in MySQL

Tags: mysql

We have two tables, `person`, which stores information about a person, and `dates` which stores dates associated with a person.

In the person table the information we care about here is

```
psref  clock   prev
1      80      
2      90   
3      100     80
4      101     90
```

`psref` is a unique reference in the table. `clock` is a current payroll number. `prev` indicates that the person was previously employed under a different payroll number.

The dates table stores dates associated with each person.

```
dtref    person   date        event
1        1        2010-01-01  1    (start)
2        1        2010-02-01  2    (leaving)
3        2        2010-01-01  1
4        2        2010-02-01  2
5        3        2010-02-02  1
6        4        2011-01-01  1
```

From the above data you can see that there are 2 scenarios for people who have returned.

**Scenario A**
Person 1 left the company on 2010-02-01 and is give a new contract the day after, with a new clock number.

**Scenario B**
Person 2 left the company on 2010-02-01 and returned a year later, 2011-01-01

I can get the start and end dates for each psref as a single line with the query below:

```
SELECT clock, prev, a.date AS StartDate, b.date AS LeavingDate
FROM person
LEFT OUTER JOIN dates a ON (psref = a.person AND a.event = 1) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dates b ON (psref = b.person AND b.event = 2)
```

What I need to do is only report one line for a person id their `prev` leaving date is 1 day prior to their current start date.

Chains are not necessarily only 1 layer deep (don't ask!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you all entries where the current job started one day after the last job (assuming `clock` and `prev` are unique values):

```
SELECT * 
FROM person tp
JOIN dates tdt 
ON (tp.psref = tdt.person AND tdt.event = 1)
join person lp
on tp.clock = lp.clock
JOIN dates ldt 
ON (lp.psref = ldt.person AND ldt.event = 2)
   and DATEDIFF(tdt.date, ldt.date) = 1;
```

If by "current" you mean that there is no end date for the current job,  you can check for this too:

```
SELECT * 
FROM person tp
JOIN dates tdt 
ON (tp.psref = tdt.person AND tdt.event = 1)
join person lp
on tp.clock = lp.clock
JOIN dates ldt 
ON (lp.psref = ldt.person AND ldt.event = 2)
   and datediff(tdt.date, ldt.date) = 1
left join dates tdtend ON (tp.psref = tdt.person AND tdt.event = 2)
where tdtend.date is null;
```

Comment: Does that only recurse through one level?

Comment: @Dan Kelly It will check every entry in the chain. The only requirement is that "previously employed" means that there is no overlap of dates (so a person can't have two jobs at the same time, and thus each job has at most one predecessor, otherwise it wouldn't be a chain). Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: Looks to work - just had a few issues resolving the abstracted case above with the real data... Just need to work out how to add our names table into the mix, but I understand what's happening here.